# Optional Characters in a Lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Say I wish to find every iteration of `orange` that is **not** preceded by `apple and` using RegEx. I also want this to work for the respective plurals.

Here's a list of what should and shouldn't be valid.

```
orange             - valid
oranges            - valid
an orange          - valid
apple and orange   - invalid
apple and oranges  - invalid
apples and orange  - invalid
apples and oranges - invalid
```

The code I've written to make this possible so far is the following.

```
(?<!apples? and )oranges?
```

When I test it, I receive an error, tracing back to the optional `s` character, after `apple`. Regex101 describes the error as the following.

> Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed.

Why is this? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look-behinds have to have a fixed length. By specifying an optional character, you indicate the length can vary by one. This is not accepted. But, you are not limited by the number of look-behinds you perform, so you can split it into two, like this:

```
(?<!apple and )(?<!apples and )oranges?
```